# AWS Elastic Beanstalk ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Tags: amazon-web-services, python-requests, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am working on an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment and I am receiving the following message:

```
[Mon May 13 12:38:41.784799 2019] [:error] [pid 3841] 
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

The message is quite obvious and I have added the module to my requirements.txt and everything is working fine on my machine but it does not work on the AWS environment.

I am just wondering if there is any trick to import modules into the AWS.

requirements.txt

```
certifi==2019.3.9
chardet==3.0.4
Django==2.1.7
django-cors-headers==2.5.2
django-extensions==2.1.6
django-filter==2.1.0
djangorestframework==3.9.2
idna==2.8
mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2018.9
requests==2.21.0
six==1.12.0
text-unidecode==1.2
urllib3==1.24.3
```

.ebextensions/django.config

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: entrypoint/wsgi.py
container_commands:
  01_wsgipass:
    command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'
```

.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml

```
branch-defaults:
  master:
    environment: XXXXX
    group_suffix: null
environment-defaults:
  squirrel-api-env:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  application_name: XXXXX
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: api-key
  default_platform: python-3.6
  default_region: ap-southeast-2
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on your project structure? Specifically, is the requirements.txt at the top-level directory of your project and deployment package?